# Aead write file in specific folder flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, storage

Anyone know how to access a particular folder in phone storage using flutter? i want to read a abc.MP4 file and save it to another location inside phone storage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [`Reading-Writing-Files documentation`](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files), there explains to you how to do it.

And I guess you want to copy the `File` to another path so you can take a look on [File.copy documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/File/copy.html)

```
Future<File> copy (
 String newPath
)
```